# htaccess error 500 while rewriterule

Tags: php, apache, web-services, .htaccess, xampp

I am following a video tutorial about the RESTful Webservice ([Creating a RESTful Web Service in PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eWC-lf1FxM)).
In this tutorial, we can pass the name of a book via URL to retrieve the price.

Here is the code :

INDEX.PHP

```
<?php
    // Process client request VIA URL
    header("Content-Type:application/json");
    include("functions.php");
    if(!empty($_GET['name']))
    {
        // if we have the name of the book in our url
        $name=$_GET['name'];
        $price=get_price($name);

        if(empty($price))
            // Book not found
            deliver_response(200,"book not found", NULL);
        else
            // Response book price
            deliver_response(200,"book_found", $price);



    }
    else
    {
        // Throw invalid request
        deliver_response(400,"invalide request", NULL);
    }

    function deliver_response($status, $status_message, $data)
    {
        header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");
        $response['status']=$status;
        $response['status_message']=$status_message;
        $response['data']=$data;

        $json_response=json_encode($response);
        echo $json_response;
    }

?>
```

FUNCTION.PHP

```
<?php
    function get_price($find)
    {
        $books=array
        (
            "java"=>299,
            "c"=>348,
            "php"=>267
        );
        foreach($books as $book=>$price)
        {
            if($book=$find)
            {
                return $price;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

.HTACCESS

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Request routing
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]*)$ index.php?name=$1 [nc, qsa]
```

While I try the tutorial without the .htaccess file, it works well.
But while I put this file to my directory, it always crash "SERVER ERROR", with a 500 error.

Can you explain it to me please ?

Comment: [nc, **space** qsa] really?

Comment: @Strakeen Thanks a lot ! It solve my problem. I didn't know space could lead to an error ! Also, what does "nc" and "qsa" mean ?

Comment: NC means NoCase, this flag is used to match a case insensitive uri /FOO or /foo both would work.

QSA is used to append old query strings to new url. For more info : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html